# WPF ChartingToolkit SizeValue doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, charts

I got problem with BubbleSeries in chartingToolkit (silverlight). I have searched a lot and read many questions and I didn't find the answer. Inside user control I got this chart:

```
         xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
```

---

```
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Height="600" Width="900" BorderThickness="0" Title="CPU Await Time" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
        <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
            <chartingToolkit:CategoryAxis Title="Lambda" Orientation="X" Height="40" />
            <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Title="Time [ms]" Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="True" Width="60" />
        </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
        <chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
            <Style TargetType="Control">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
        <chartingToolkit:BubbleSeries SizeValueBinding="{Binding Size}" DependentValuePath="Val.CPUAwaitTime" IndependentValuePath="Key" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding ResultsList}" IsSelectionEnabled="False" />
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Without this SizeValueBinging everything works ok, but after I placed it there none of the bubbles are displayed. I really exhausted all ideas, only one left is some assembly problems which I already had. I downloaded silverlight from MS site and added "System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll" reference, after this it still didn't work (I was getting errors in wpf) so then I used this "Install-Package System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" command in package manager console and charts sorted working, but not this SizeValueBinding.

Thank you in advance for any help.

---

Here is (part of) ViewModel (I know I should use full property and make it look pretty but it's only updated in one place and I don't need extra code):

```
    NormalViewModel Overwatch { get; set; }
    public double[] Lambdas { get; private set; }
    public List<KeyVal<string,LStats.Results>> ResultsList { get; private set; }
    public double Size { get; set; } = 34;

    public class KeyVal<TKey, TVal>
    {
        public TKey Key { get; set; }
        public TVal Val { get; set; }

        public KeyVal(TKey Key, TVal Val)
        {
            this.Key = Key;
            this.Val = Val;
        }
    }

    public LSearchViewModel(NormalViewModel Overwatch)
    {
        this.Overwatch = Overwatch;
    }

    public override void Simulate()
    {
        Lambdas = new double[Overwatch.NumOfLambdas];
        ResultsList = new List<KeyVal<string, LStats.Results>>();
        Action[] mySimulations = new Action[Overwatch.NumOfLambdas];
        for (int i = 0; i < Overwatch.NumOfLambdas; i++)
        {
            Lambdas[i] = Math.Round(Overwatch.Lambda + (Overwatch.NumOfLambdas / 2 - i) * Overwatch.LambdaSpan, 5);
            CreateList(i);

            var _temp = i;
            mySimulations[i] = new Action(() => SetLambda(_temp));
        }
        Parallel.Invoke(mySimulations);
        OnPropertyChanged("Size");
        OnPropertyChanged("ResultsList");
    }
```

---

Question can be marked as answered. There ware two problem:

- It appears I must use SizeValuePath and "bind it" to property of the list item.
- The size of the bubbles cannot be absolute, what this size value path does is simply setting proportional value between different bubbles.

Thank you to @jstreet for helping me with this one.

Comment: You probably should use `SizeValuePath` rather than `SizeValueBinding`, but it depends on your `ViewModel`.

Comment: I actually tried them both (that's why I didn't specify this in title). If I understand them correctly SizeValuePath refers to the specific property in class of which type is the list and SizeValueBinding refers to the property in the ViewModel. In my case I need second but I could live with first one but neither of them works. My Size property is of type double, maybe that's the problem. I could not find any information about type of that other than "Numeric".

Comment: I tried the simplest binding, using `SizeValuePath`, where `Size` property is a `double`, and it worked with no problem. Please post your `ViewModel`.

Comment: @jstreet I have added ViewModel.

Comment: OK i see the problem....

Comment: Unless `Size` is part of the elements contained in `ResultList` collection, i don't see an immediate solution.

Comment: @jstreet I checked once again SizeValuePath I did made mistake previously and didn't place "Val" in the path, after I added this bubbles do display but the size value doesn't have real impact on size of bubbles. They are made equal, that's correct but they aren't of the size I want them to be (I tried range from 0.001 to 300 and there was no difference). I am sorry for misleading you at first. Still would like to make it work with binding as well.

Comment: From what I have seen, the size of the bubbles are proportional to each other. So, if `Size` is 25 for one bubble and 100 for another, one will be 4 times larger than the other. But not sure you could get **absolute** sizes for the bubbles.

Comment: Well then it's useless to me anyway, I was looking for elegant way of indicating confidence interval.

So now I understand that when I assign SizeValuePath of every bubble to the same value they just got the same size. That's disappointing. But thank you for you help, I would have struggle with it way longer if it wasn't for you. I don't know if I should delete question?

Comment: Why can't you assign different values then?

Comment: @jstreet The values "DependentValuePath" are results of simulation and every result has it's own confidence interval. I thought that inticating it with size of bubble is simple idea and ended up with those problems. I will probably implement it with different chart placed on this one. Maybe it won't be that elegant but still it should work.

Comment: OK good luck then.